# Send Friend request with facebook graph api in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating iphone app with facebook graph api. I am able to get list of my friends.. Any body knows how to send friend request to any user ?

and I am also trying to get particular FriendList ,,,

searched this [Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/)

But how can I get this FriendList ID ???

> /FRIENDLIST_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook Graph API doesn't support adding friends.

To get a list of their friend lists, you need `read_friendlists` extended permission.  Then, you can call https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendlists which will return all of their friends lists, with a name and the friend list id you are looking for. You can test this with the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friendlists) (check box for read_friendlists permission).