# Facebook friend Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send Friend request with facebook graph api in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548407/send-friend-request-with-facebook-graph-api-in-iphone)

I have an issue in sending a friend request in facebook through my iphone app. I dint find any api for that. If anyone here could help me out in this i wud be very thankfull to them.

Thanks 
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot send Friend Request using the API. But you can direct users to User's page, inside webView to see the Friend request button.